# Is it possible to call one custom keyword function from another Custom keywords from katalon Automation Tool?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, uiautomation

I am trying to call method from one custom keywords to another Custom keywords functions

But I am getting below error,

> 05-30-2018 02:59:02 PM - [START]  - Start action :
>   mandatoryfield_Validation.Mandatoryfieldvalidation.textfieldvalidation
>   05-30-2018 02:59:02 PM - [INFO]   - Finding Test Object with id
>   'Object
>   Repository/HelpDeskModule/Master/Team/Page_eFACiLiTY/input_Txt_Code'
>   05-30-2018 02:59:02 PM - [ERROR]  - No such property: CustomKeywords
>   for class: mandatoryfield_Validation.Mandatoryfieldvalidation
>   05-30-2018 02:59:02 PM - [END]    - End action :
>   mandatoryfield_Validation.Mandatoryfieldvalidation.textfieldvalidation
>   05-30-2018 02:59:02 PM - [ERROR]  - Test
>   Cases/HelpDeskModule/Master/Team_/Team FAILED because (of) Variable
>   'CustomKeywords' is not defined for test case.

```java
public class Mandatoryfieldvalidation {
//<!--Initializing object-->

private static Connection connection = null;
private static  String columntype;
private static int num;
private static int datatypevalue
def driver = DF.getWebDriver()
KeywordLogger logger = new KeywordLogger()
JavascriptExecutor js = ((driver) as JavascriptExecutor)

    //Method for validating textfield
    @Keyword
    def void textfieldvalidation()
    {
        CustomKeywords.'alerthandling.verifyalertpresent.verifyalert'()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of
`CustomKeywords.'alerthandling.verifyalertpresent.verifyalert'()`

use
`(new alerthandling.verifyalertpresent()).verifyalert()`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you need to import corresponding packages.
By the looks of it, you should try this:

```
import alerthandling.verifyalertpresent
```